# Trouble with overflow and whitespace

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble in the navbar, on the left hand side there is a blank space before the first action (Home), the second issue I'm having is the Div which contains the left and right div has overflowed from the .container, if anyone could help that would be most appreciated.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/13qn4qfa/

Comment: Does [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/13qn4qfa/1/) solve your blank space problem? and regading the second problem, i actually didnt get you..

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/n19rl3I.png on the navbar there is extra space at the beginning as marked by the circle, on the div the div goes past the line of where the navbar is so it's not inline with the navbar.

Comment: ok..add `.navbar-nav{margin-top:0;}` to your css and see if the first problem is solved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to overwritte some css applied:

add this:

```
.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 0px; 
  padding-left: 0px; 
}
.row {
  margin-right: 0px; 
  margin-left: 0px; 
}  
.navbar-collapse {
      padding-left: 0px;
    }
.navbar .container-fluid {
    padding-right:15px;
    }
```

**[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/13qn4qfa/3/)**

Edited: new **[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/13qn4qfa/6/)** with this new added css:

```
.navbar-nav {
    padding-left:30px;
}
.container-fluid>.navbar-header{
    margin-right: -15px;
}
div#navbar {
    margin-left:0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It's almost perfect, except on mobile view the menu links are not inline with the menu, http://i.imgur.com/9XWa3mF.png - http://fiddle.jshell.net/13qn4qfa/5/

Comment: Even if it's VERY rude to unmark an answer that SOLVED perfectly your question... exactly what you asked for, I edited my answer with new rules added and i will make  a suggestion. It's much better to learn bootstrap and what classes you need to achieve your results than asking other to make the work for you without even trying (or at least it is what it looks now after uncheking the right answer mark and making your comment). I don't care if you check it back now, just, for the future, try to show an effort and more people will be willing to help you.

Comment: I'm very sorry Alvaro Menéndez, please accept my apologies, it was a genuine mistake, I am extremely grateful for your help.